# How to use dblclick event in highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am working with Highcharts. I need to make drilldown when series is double clicked. I found an example with Highmaps at this url:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/p29wnkp5/3/
```

but in my solution dbclick, the event doesn't fire.

My example code is at this link:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztmprq
```

In this example, I only want to handle with double click and click. I want to fire different functions. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, please include your relevant code in the question rather than linking to it. Remember that StackOverflow is a Q&A knowledge base, and thus information provided must remain valid into the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double click event isnt part of highchart, in the fiddle you will notice that its an extrnal module

```
<script src="http://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/js/customEvents.js"></script>
```

The custom events module is available on bower or npm so should be easy to add to your project

```
bower install highcharts-custom-events
```

or

```
npm i highcharts-custom-events --save
```

from here you can import it to angular as follow.

```
import * as  Highcharts from 'highcharts';   
import customEvents from 'highcharts-custom-events';
customEvents(Highcharts);
```

updated working fiddle
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzkby6